# Is it possible to conform to Decodable with async init(from: Decoder)?

Tags: swift, async-await

I have a function that queries a cloud database for results and is `async`:

```
func getFromDB(id: myIDType) async -> ResultsType{
   //retrieve stuff from DB, searching by id
}
```

I also have a class that I need to make it conform to `Codable` so I can upload objects created from it to the same cloud database. The caveat is that this class has a reference to another class, and I only intend to store on the DB a reference to its `id`. So then the function to conform to the protocol is:

```
required init(from: Decoder) async throws {
//init all my other properties

decodedID = //decode the ID retrieved from the DB on this decoder
referencedObject = try await getFromDB(id: decodedID) //retrieve the referenced object from the ID stored.

//error Handling and such.
}
```

As of now, with this code, I'm getting a compiler error stating the class doesn't conform to Decodable, everything points to the fact that this `required init` cannot be async.

So, is this possible? How?

Comment: No, it's not, `Codable` is synchronous. Asynchronous tasks in `init` methods is bad practice anyway.

Comment: How would you solve this? What would be a good practice approach for this situation?

Comment: Is your upload function asynchronous? Can you provide some detail on the implementation of upload method?

Comment: @SoumyaMahunt its actually a download function and yes it is async. The implementation is just a normal firebase query. I run a whereField query on the database and retrieve its documents. This is the async operation. Something like `try await databaseRef.collection(collectionPath).whereField("someField", isEqualTo: "some value").getDocuments()`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to retrieve the `referencedObject` value in the initializer you can just create a task that fetches your object in the background and then create computed property that provides access to your object value. So the final code becomes something like this:

```swift
private var objectRetrievalTask: Task<ObjectType, Error>!

var referencedObject: ObjectType {
    get async throws {
        try await objectRetrievalTask.value
    }
}

required init(from: Decoder) throws {
    //init all my other properties
    decodedID //decode the ID retrieved from the DB on this decoder
    objectRetrievalTask = Task { try await self.getFromDB(id: decodedID) } //run task in background to retrieve the referenced object from the ID stored.

    //error Handling and such.
}
```